# Need to update TextController with Provider

Tags: flutter, textfield, flutter-provider

Currently, I'm learning flutter and can't update one textController when the value in provider changes.
Here is the code I tried already:

```
TextEditingController textController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    TranslateTextProvider myProvider = Provider.of<TranslateTextProvider>(
      context,
      listen: false,
    );

    super.initState();
    textController = TextEditingController(text: myProvider.translated);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

The provider is updating correctly but textfield doesn't and yes I have set the controller on textfield.
I'll be grateful for every tip.

Comment: could you add the textfield code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you need to listen to dependencies updates, you need to use `didChangeDependencies` ! This is triggered if you are listening to a provider which is updated.

Here is you example adapted:

```dart
TextEditingController textController;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  textController = TextEditingController();
}

@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  textController.text = Provider.of<TranslateTextProvider>(
    context,
    listen: true, // Be sure to listen
  ).text;
  super.didChangeDependencies();
}

@override
void dispose() {
  textController.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Of course your `Provider` has to dispatch the changes, if you are using a `ChangeNotifier` for example, it would imply calling `notifyListeners`  (if you ChangeNotifier) whenever the text is updated:

```dart
class TranslateTextProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  String _text = "";

  String get text => _text;

  set text(String newText) {
    if (newText != text) {
      _text = newText;
      notifyListeners(); // Notify if the text changed
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [ChangeNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html) do not have any method called `notifyDependencies`.

Comment: `notifyListeners` my bad ;) I added an example

Comment: Thank you very for your help but i tried that and it gave me this error:                       
The following assertion was thrown building RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#ce7ca](state: RawGestureDetectorState#31d2f(gestures: <none>, behavior: opaque)):
dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_InheritedProviderScope<TranslateTextProvider>>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _TranslatorState.initState() completed.

Comment: Remove the text fetching from initState. I updated the example

Comment: Im not sure where is the problem, there is no error anymore but the controller does still not update :(

Comment: Oh I made some other changes in logic and it actually works, thank you very much.

Comment: Ahah my pleasure. Be sure to accept the upvote and validate the answer if it solve your issue :)

Comment: I think I'm not allowed to do that beacuse I don't have 15 reputation, is there any other way to +rep you ?

Comment: Oh no worries accepting is enough. Upvoting is just nice in case another answer appears but since I'm alone here it should be fine ;)